# Virtual assignment operator

Tags: c++

Given the code below, shouldn't `Calling B` be printed, not `Calling A`? Isn't the runtime type of `a` a `B` and hence the virtual call should result in a call to `B::operator=` (as virtual calls are determined by the left operand)?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  virtual A& operator=(const A& a_) { std::cout << "Calling A" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  virtual B& operator=(const B& b_) { std::cout << "Calling B" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  B b1;
  B b2;
  A& a = b1;
  a = b2; // Prints "Calling A", should be "Calling B"?

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no `A::operator=(const B& b_)`, only `A::operator=(const A& a_)`

Comment: Virtual assignment is an ungood idea because it introduces **run time type-checking**, moving bug detection etc. to run-time with more extensive and unreliable testing.

Comment: I you want to see `Calling B` message you should try this `virtual B& operator=(const A& b_) override { std::cout << "Calling B" << std::endl; return *this; }` in class B.

Comment: You should also always `return *this` when overriding `operator=`.

Comment: @Cheers: What is your suggestion to do instead? In some situations a virtual clone method might suffice, but that's not allways the case.

Comment: @MikeMB: Depends. I've never needed it, so it's very rarely needed. I can't think of a situation where it would be needed, but if that occurred, I'd think long and hard about changing design, i.e. I'd treat it as a design smell.

Answer (score 4):

`a = b2;` is **not** a virtual call.

The reason for this is that `B::operator=(const B&)` does not override `A::operator=(const A&)`, because their signatures are different.

You can use `override` to make the compiler automatically check these things for you.

Using `override` does two things:

- prevents simple errors like this (compiler is your best friend)
- makes the code easier to understand ("oh so this function overrides something")

Comment: Isn't it still a virtual call (compiler optimizations aside)? Just one with only a single virtual function it can be resolved to?

Comment: Plus one for `override`, that's the intended use case for it

Comment: Example usage of `override`?

Comment: @user3728501 In base class: `virtual void foo();`, in derived class: `void foo() override;`

Answer (score 2):

The virtual method you have in B `(B::operator=(const B&))` doesn't override the one in A `(A::operator=(const A&))`. I am guessing what you've written is an overload, therefore, compiler can't know such a method exists since you are using an A reference.

Answer (score 2):

This method:

```
virtual B& operator=(const B& b_)
```

doesn't override this method:

```
virtual A& operator=(const A& a_)
```

In order for it to override the base class's method, the child has to have the same method signature.

Calling `A::operator=` does not defer implementation to the derived class because the derived class has no implementation of `virtual A& operator=(const A& a_)`.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an object of `class A`, `a = b2` of cause will call `A& operator=(const A& a_)` where type of`b2` will be converted to type `A`. Testing `b1 = b2` will output "Calling B".

`operator=` overriding is unique for each class. There is no point to declare it as virtual function.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as everyone else already said, your override doesn't - it's just an overload. Use the override keyword to confirm this.

The solution is to give the derived class operator *exactly* the same signature as the base class one, taking A, and dynamic_cast that to B in the body.

You'll need to consider what to do if the caller tries assigning an A to a B though (ie, the cast fails). As Alf mentioned in a comment, this is the reason virtual assignment isn't very popular.

Answer (score -1):

It will call only A::operator= . .As it's method overloading scenario which you can't achieve in two different classes(even it's inheriting) because of name hiding feature in c++.

Comment: It calls `virtual A& operator=(const A& a_)` because there is no `virtual B& operator=(const B& b_)` in the base class. It's not the same method.

Comment: But they had the same signature right as operator=? Functions with same name and different types of args . .

Comment: They don''t have the same signature. One is `A& operator=(const A& a_)`, the other is `B& operator=(const B&)`. It doesn't have to do with name hiding. It's just overloading.

Comment: I think that's what Karthik means (it's an overload rather than an override), but it isn't entirely clear.